# Google Base Query Problems

Tags: .net, gdata-api, google-base

I am querying Google Base using the .NET library pretty much as described on this page.

http://code.google.com/apis/base/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

When I run the query a GBaseFeed is returned and it will usually have the TotalRecords property set to something like 35, but in the Entries collection it will often have no items or very few items. Other times the query returns all 35 items as expected in the Entries. Has anyone seen this behaviour or have any idea what could cause it?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research it appears the TotalResults attribute in the Google Base feeds is basically not functional and probably should not be relied upon.